# amsthm: how to reduce the vertical spacing between theorem and proof?

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I'm using the amsthm package to layout theorems and their proofs.  How can I reduce the vertical spacing between the last line of the theorem statement and the first line of the proof?

BTW, I tried achieving this by fiddling with the third parameter to

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{4ex}{-4ex}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{3ex}{}
```

...but even negative values (as illustrated above) failed to bring the first line of the proof closer than a certain fixed distance of about 2.5 line heights.

A related question: how can I prevent pagebreaks between the theorem and the proof?  I would like to ensure that at least two lines from the theorem statement precede the first line of a proof on a page.  (One may fairly assume that there is no text interposed between the last line of the theorem statement and the first line of the proof.)

Comment: It is good to take look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68413/157031

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility would be to redefine the `proof` anvironment as defined in `amsthm.sty` (the definition uses `\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax`, so you could make some changes there). Another approach would be to use the front-end [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) to define a new theorem-like structure behaving like the standard `proof` environment, but using the `spaceabove` key to control the vertical space above it. The following example illustrates this second approach and shows the different spacing for the new `prf` environment and the standard `proof` environment:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem} 
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=-6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  qed=\qedsymbol%
]{mystyle} 
\declaretheorem[name={Proof},style=mystyle,unnumbered,
]{prf}

\begin{document} 

\begin{theorem} 
A really important result.
\end{theorem}
\begin{prf} 
And its proof with less space above.
\end{prf} 
\begin{theorem} 
A really important result.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof} 
And its proof with too much space above.
\end{proof} 

\end{document}
```

[image]