# Remove vertical space around theorems

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I'm very new to LaTeX (a couple of days ago I didn't know how to use `\newtheorem`) and was hoping someone could help me with the following problem.

If I'm using `\usepackage{amsthm}`, how do I obtain control over the vertical gap between Theorems, Propositions etc and their respective proofs? In particular, I am looking for the proof to follow on like a normal line. This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
\usepackage{amthm}

\newtheoremstyle{newstyle}      
{} %Aboveskip 
{-.25pt} %Below skip
{\mdseries} %Body font e.g.\mdseries,\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{} %Indent
{\bfseries} %Head font e.g.\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{.} %Punctuation afer theorem header
{ } %Space after theorem header
{} %Heading

\theoremstyle{newstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[thm]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\newenvironment{pf}
{\n\textit{Proof.}\begin{mdseries}}
{\end{mdseries}}\
```

However, I have two main problems with it. Firstly, the `%Below skip` doesn't seem to give me much control - there's a pretty substantial jump between `{}` and when I type any negative value in. Secondly, the numbering is mucked up e.g. if I was to type `\begin{thm}...\end{thm}` and then `\begin{prop}...\end{prop}` (in section 1 say) I would get as my out put:

> Theorem 1.1
>   Proposition 1.1.1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code sample is truncated, can you supply the rest?

Comment: Have you considered using the `proof` environment provided by the `amsthm` package? Among other things, it does a very nice job of placing and end-of-proof ("qed") symbol at the end of the environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, below skip should be positive, negative values are ignored.  You can clear the spacing provided as standard by writing

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{\thm@preskip=0pt
\thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother
```

before your `\newtheoremstyle`.  You can adjust this by changing the values `0pt` or using the parameters in the `\newtheoremstyle`.

Try

```
\newenvironment{pf}{\noindent\textit{Proof.}\begin{mdseries}}{\end{mdseries}}
```

for your proof environment.  If this is too simplistic, e.g. if you wish to have the `\qed` features of the AMS environment, then you can use the following adaption of the AMS proof code

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{pf}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
  #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

The important point is setting the value of `\topsep` to zero.

Lastly, the proposition number is wrong because you have asked it to be numbered within `thm`s!  You should write

```
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
```

with `[thm]` placed between the other arugments not at the end.

Here is this all put in to one sample document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{\thm@preskip=0pt
\thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother
\newtheoremstyle{newstyle}      
{} %Aboveskip 
{} %Below skip
{\mdseries} %Body font e.g.\mdseries,\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{} %Indent
{\bfseries} %Head font e.g.\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{.} %Punctuation afer theorem header
{ } %Space after theorem header
{} %Heading

\theoremstyle{newstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{pf}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep0\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
  #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text to indicate the spacing.

\begin{thm}
  First theorem, with sufficiently long text so that it spills on to a
  second line.
\end{thm}

Some text to indicate the spacing.  Fill-up text make this spill on to
an extra line.  Fill-up text make this spill on to an extra line.

More text.

\begin{prop}
  A proposition, with sufficiently long text so that it spills on to a
  second line.
\end{prop}

\begin{pf}
  Proof of the proposition with \verb+pf+ environment and sufficiently
  long text so that it spills on to a second line.
\end{pf}

\begin{prop}
  Another proposition, with sufficiently long text so that it spills
  on to a second line.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
  The original proof environment and sufficiently long text so that it
  spills on to a second line.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks your answer. You've certainly cleared up 2, but as I'm looking for the proof to follow on like a normal line, I'm still stick on 1!

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- the text for the theorem consists only of short paragraphs, nothing that goes to a second line.  this gives the impression that the theorem text is always indented, which it wouldn't be under ordinary circumstances.  maybe break the text into lines with `\\` (which *shouldn't* be done normally!), or just add enough text after "first theorem" to fill the first line and start to a second.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  You are right.  I have updated the sample document.

Comment: @user32259 I have addressed this now.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Just one last thing... how would you make a proof environment in a similar way to the theorems where you can change the space before and after? I tried using your code for `\makeletter` and substituting `thm` for `pf` but it didn't work.

Comment: @user32259 You can change the value of `\topsep` from `0\p@` (which is just `0pt`) to some other value to get space above the proof.  Space below is achieved by inserting e.g. `\vskip 10pt` after the final `\@endpefalse`.  You might want to make these values flexible by adding some glue, e.g. `\vskip 10pt plus 2pt`, meaning nominally 10pt but increasable to 12pt.