# Removing vertical space around a Proposition without using amsthm package

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

I am using a custom document class `risa` as specified by a journal (available from: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291539-6924/homepage/ForAuthors.html. Download link: http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/pdf/risa.zip.). Seems like this class has a conflict with the `amsthm` package, because the use of `\usepackage{amsthm}` in the preamble gives an error: "Command \theoremstyle already defined." Hence, without using `amsthm` package, I am trying to remove some blank space that appears before and after a proposition. An MWE (which is quite long, sorry I couldn't find a better way to show the issue) is presented at the end.

My preamble is

```
\documentclass{risa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
```

I use commands similar to:

```
...
\begin{prop}
Proposition 2 here
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
Proof to Proposition 2 here
\end{proof}
...
```

There are 3 propositions, and the unwanted vertical space is observed only around Proposition 2. FYI, the `risa` class uses uses `twocolumn` page layout. I tried using `\vspace{-1cm}` etc. and tried changing the argument value, and found that low values (~0.5cm} did not produce any effect, but higher values (~1cm) made the Proposition jump up too much and overlap the preceding text. The closest answer I found was here: [Remove vertical space around theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68408/remove-vertical-space-around-theorems), but that suggests using `amsthm` package which I cannot.

Please suggest whats wrong here. Thank you!

**Edit added on Dec 27, 2016:**
I understood that an equation which appears on the top of the next column (given in the MWE) forces the Proposition environment to leave unwanted vertical space before and after. Please note that in there is only one Proposition in the MWE (not three as mentioned previously).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[sort&compress]{risa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{1pt plus 2pt minus1.5pt}% default: {12pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\setlength\theorempostskipamount{1pt plus 2pt minus1.5pt}% default: {8pt plus 3pt minus 1.5pt}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\begin{document}

\title[Title]{Title of the Article}

\author[Author]{First Last,$^{1}$\affiliation{Department, University}}
\begin{abstract}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016-17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
keyword A, keyword B, keyword C
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}
The Premier League\cite{1} is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

\begin{prop}
\label{prop:epl}
The Premier League is (a) an English professional league for men's association football clubs,
(b) the country's primary football competition, and
(c) contested by 20 clubs.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016-17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. 

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \frac{\partial K}{\partial c_{a}} &=& \frac{u'_{a}(- c_{a}) }{ u_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a})-u_{a}(- c_{a})}\\
    &-& \frac{[u_{a}(0)-u_{a}(- c_{a})](u'_{a}(- c_{a}) - u'_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a}))}{[ u_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a})-u_{a}(- c_{a})]^{2}},
\end{eqnarray*}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify. \hfill $\blacksquare$
\end{proof}
\bigskip

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}
Wikipedia.org. Premier League; 2016. Available at: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League}, Accessed on December 27, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have been given a template/class by a journal to use, don't change it. You are not the designer, the journal are. You provide the contents they make the decision on how things should look. So you might be wasting your own and the journals time.

Comment: Thanks, for sure I don't want to go against the 'class' rules. But there is no uniformity here, because Propositions 1 and 3 do not have extra blank spaces, whereas Proposition 2 does. If the class has specific rules, then the behavior should be the same for all three Propositions. I am hopeful that this is something that can be set right without tampering with the class file, and by just using some  easy workarounds.

Comment: Without a full minimal example we cannot know. Please provide something others can try out that show this large gap. Then we can suggest remedies. But again, it is mostly a lost cause, especially in two column mode. Everything depends on the exact contents. The large stretch may come from large pieces of math that cannot be broken. Or something else, we do not know.

Comment: @daleif, I understand. I will try to post a MWE here soon.

Comment: @daleif : I added a MWE. As you said, looks like the math is causing the problem here - does that mean that rearranging the positions of math/text in the document is the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `risa.cls` uses the `theorem`package, which is not compatible with `amsthm`.

You can change the values of `\theorempreskipamount` and `theorempostskipamount`:

```
\documentclass{risa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{6pt plus 2pt minus1.5pt}% default: {12pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\setlength\theorempostskipamount{6pt plus 2pt minus1.5pt}% default: {8pt plus 3pt minus 1.5pt}
 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{prop}
  Proposition 2 here
\end{prop}\begin{proof}
Proof to Proposition 2 here
\end{proof}
\lipsum[47]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*

The main problem with your mwe is due to the multiline equation. You should *not* use `eqnarray`, which is deprecated and has bad spacings around the alignment point. Furter, it cannot break across pages/columns. Replace it with the ams environment  `align*` instead and use the directive `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

I changed you values for `theorempre/postskipamount` to more sensible values, and added a `\vspace{-\topsep}` between the proposition and its proof. Note the proof environment is not implemented as a theorem structure, but only as a trivlist, hence the negative `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass[sort&compress]{risa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\setlength\theorempreskipamount{3pt plus 1.5pt minus1.5pt}% default: {12pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}
\setlength\theorempostskipamount{2.5pt plus 1.5pt minus 1pt}% default: {8pt plus 3pt minus 1.5pt}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\title[Title]{Title of the Article}

\author[Author]{First Last,$^{1}$\affiliation{Department, University}}
\begin{abstract}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016-17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
keyword A, keyword B, keyword C
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\pagebreak
\section{Introduction}
The Premier League\cite{1} is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

\begin{prop}
\label{prop:epl}
The Premier League is (a) an English professional league for men's association football clubs,
(b) the country's primary football competition, and
(c) contested by 20 clubs.
\end{prop}
\vspace*{-\topsep}
%%
\begin{proof}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016-17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition.
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial K}{\partial c_{a}} &= \frac{u'_{a}(- c_{a}) }{ u_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a})-u_{a}(- c_{a})}\\
    &- \frac{[u_{a}(0)-u_{a}(- c_{a})](u'_{a}(- c_{a}) - u'_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a}))}{[ u_{a}(v_{a} - c_{a})-u_{a}(- c_{a})]^{2}},
\end{align*}
The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify. \hfill $\blacksquare$
\end{proof}
%\bigskip

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

The Premier League is an English professional league for men's association football clubs. At the top of the English football league system, it is the country's primary football competition. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League (EFL; known as "The Football League" before 2016–17). Welsh clubs that compete in the English football league system can also qualify.

The Premier League is a corporation in which the 20 member clubs act as shareholders. Seasons run from August to May. Teams play 38 matches each (playing each team in the league twice, home and away), totalling 380 matches in the season. Most games are played on Saturday and Sunday afternoons; others during weekday evenings. It is colloquially known as the Premiership and outside the UK it is commonly referred to as the English Premier League (EPL).

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}
Wikipedia.org. Premier League; 2016. Available at: \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League}, Accessed on December 27, 2016.
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]
    \end{document}

Comment: I tried this, and it reduces a little bit of the unwanted space, but not the whole of it. I understood that a specific equation that comes at the top of the next column is forcing the Proposition environment to leave some space before and after. The question is edited and gives a MWE now.