# Inconsistent spacing with parskip option of KOMA script and amsthm

Tags: koma-script, amsthm, parskip

This problem is similar to [Question 25346](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25346), however the proposed solution does not solve my problem.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{definition} 
In luctus mattis felis ac tristique.
\end{definition}

Nunc vulputate lectus at eros vehicula.

Aliquam fermentum eu justo in lobortis. 
\end{document}
```

produces inconsistent spacing:

---

[image]

---

Adding

```
\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@for\theoremstyle:=definition,remark,plain\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname th@\theoremstyle\endcsname{%
            \addtolength\thm@preskip\parskip
            }%
        }
\endgroup
```

to the preamble, as suggested in [Question 25346](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25346) produces

---

[image]

---

but this space is now significantly bigger than the paragraph skip. I would like the the text-to-theorem-skip be identical in size to the parskip. Thanks!

Comment: `\addtolength` increases the value of what's already there.  i think what you want is to *reset* the value of `\thm@preskip to equal that of `\parskip`.  if that's the case, why don't you just do it directly, using `\setlength`?  (the definitions in `amsthm` are a little more complicated though, so more changes might be involved.  and you might want also to consider `\thm@postskip`; having that larger than the preskip seems rather unusual.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code results in essentially two `\parskip`s before and after the definition.  Before the theorem you can set the spacing to `\parskip` by using `\setlength` rather than `\addtolength` in the adjustment of `\thm@preskip`.  For after the theorem the relevant quantity is `\thm@postskip`, but this needs to be put to zero, as there comes a `\parskip` anyway:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}

\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@for\theoremstyle:=definition,remark,plain\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname th@\theoremstyle\endcsname{%
            \setlength\thm@preskip\parskip
            \setlength\thm@postskip{0pt}
            }%
        }
\endgroup

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\show\definition

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{definition} 
In luctus mattis felis ac tristique.
\end{definition}

Nunc vulputate lectus at eros vehicula.

Aliquam fermentum eu justo in lobortis. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it works nicely. I still had to combine your suggestion with the answer to [Question 28165](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28166/4912), to achieve consistent spacing also in the proof-environment.

Comment: And the result is very poor, I should add.

Comment: @egreg: Do you mean in regards to my comment? I did in fact end up using your suggestion from [Question 59755](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59769/4912) instead, as there were some incompatibilites with my document.

Comment: @FelixHoffmann I think that spaced paragraphs are evil and Andrew's example clearly shows why.

Comment: @egreg At most it shows they become evil in LaTeX. My students tell me they are the modern way and they learnt in college that indenting paragraphs is old-fashioned.

Comment: @cfr Explain them that it used to be fashionable a century ago